# Redrive data in Kinesis stream to Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, triggers, amazon-kinesis

I have a very simple Lambda right now that is triggered by Kinesis and it's all hooked up and working fine...but I want to work through the case where I found a bug in my lambda code and need to re-run data that is still available in the stream (my stream is setup to retain data for 7 days).

Is there an easy way to do this?  I was hoping there would be something in the console to "reset" the sequence position for the lambda but I couldn't find that.

One method I've tested is to delete the original trigger and add a new one with the position as `TRIM_HORIZON` but wondering if there's an easier way to do this (my original trigger was setup w/ `LATEST`).

Answer (score 0):

If you have to reprocess the whole data from Kinesis stream, there is no other way except recreating the Trigger.

`STARTING_POSITION` can't be updated for the existing triggers. Only certain properties are allowed to be updated using [UpdateEventSourceMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateEventSourceMapping.html) command.

Updating  `STARTING_POSITION` in EventSourceMapping will impact the committed checkpoints in Kinesis as it determines how many records are processed and where the current position is committed.   Whenever a new trigger is created, It starts checkpointing the records processing from Kinesis.